# Define function- donuts

Tags: python-3.x

[image]Folks,

I am trying to do Google Python Class and am at the early stage of learning Python.
I am not able to do a proper `return`/`print`.
I have this code:

```
def donuts(count):
    if count < 10:
        pcount=count
        print('Number of donuts: %s' %count)
    else:
        print('Number of donuts: many')
    return
```

And the below code from Google:

```
def test(got, expected):
    if got == expected:
        prefix = ' OK '
    else:
        prefix = '  X '
        print('%s got: %s expected: %s' % (prefix, repr(got), repr(expected)))

def main():
    print('donuts')
    test(donuts(4), 'Number of donuts: 4')
    test(donuts(9), 'Number of donuts: 9')
    test(donuts(10), 'Number of donuts: many')
    test(donuts(99), 'Number of donuts: many')

if __name__ == '__main__':   main()
```

Comment: Rather than using print in function donuts, just return the string i.e. remove `print ()` and use `return` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tests you posted expect you to `return` the string rather then `print`ing it :)

Few other suggestions:

1. You can remove the bare `return` from the end of the function. Python will return `None` anyway, even if you won't specify it.
2. You don't use `pcount`, so you can leave it out.
3. Space before and after operators to comply with [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```py
    def donuts(count):
        if count < 10:
            return 'Number of donuts: %s' % count
        else:
            return 'Number of donuts: many'
```

Comment: i did what you suggested. but something is messed up as i am not getting any prints. Please review the screen shot i attached. Thank you very much

Comment: The `print` in the `test` function should be dedented.